# VB.NET: Is there a way to keep Nothing from defaulting to 0 for number types?

Tags: vb.net

It's really bugging me that the VS 2010 IDE isn't barking at me for trying to pass Nothing through a method parameter that takes an user-defined enum.  Instead, it's passing 0 through to the method.  c# would never allow this.  Is there some module-level modifier I can add like `option strict` that will force the IDE to not allow these types of implicit conversions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly, no.

---

But you can assign values to your enumeration members while skipping `0` (or use a placeholder named `None` or something like that), and at least handle this case at run time.

```
Sub Main
    MyMethod(Nothing) ' throws Exception
End Sub

Sub MyMethod(e as MyEnum)
    If e = 0 Then
        Throw New Exception
    End If
End Sub

Enum MyEnum
    a=1
    b=2
    c=3
End Enum
```

Comment: Good answer, but it makes me sad.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is the equivalent of *default* in the C# language.  So no.

Reconsider your programming style, *Nothing* should be used *very* sparingly.  Basically only in generic code, same place you'd use *default* in C#.  You don't need it anywhere else, VB.NET doesn't insist on variable initialization like C# does.  Any variable of a reference type gets initialized to Nothing automatically.  Cringe-worthy to a C# programmer perhaps, but entirely idiomatic in VB.NET code.

Comment: I don't think it's easily possible to avoid literal `Nothing` as a method parameter (which is the case that the OP is talking about).

Comment: That's possible too, optional parameters have always been well supported.